# Bubble Sort Display

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int data[], int n);

int main()
{
cout << "Enter ten unsorted integers..." << endl;

int a[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++  i)
{
    cout << "[" << i << "] = ";
    cin >> a[i];
}

cout << endl << "Unsorted List = ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    cout << a[i] << ", ";

cout << endl;

cout << "Sorting..." << endl;
cout << "Sorted List = ";
bubbleSort(a, 10);
}

void bubbleSort(int data[], int n)
{
int j = 0;
bool nextEnd = true;
while (nextEnd)
{
    nextEnd = false;
    ++j;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - j; ++i) 
    {
        if (data[i] > data[i+1]) 
        {
            int temp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[i+1];
            data[i+1] = data[i];
            nextEnd = true;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
cout << data[i] << ", ";
}
```

The program is really simple. Input ten values to an array. Display them unsorted. Send them into the bubbleSort function, sort them and finally display the sorted list. The problem I'm having is I don't get the outputting back to work. I tested with the last line of code but that doesn't work. I don't think my sorting is messed up either. How can I display this sorted list properly?

Comment: The way you're displaying the output is fine.  The problem must be in the bubble sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your 'swap'.  It should be:

```
int temp = data[i];
data[i] = data[i+1];
data[i+1] = temp;
```

Edit-Tested and works fine with the correction.

Answer (score 3):

There is at least one error in the bubble sort.  The assignment to `data[i+1]` is not correct.  It should be:

```
data[i+1] = temp;
```

Comment: Ah. Too tired for this I guess. Should've gone through it more carefully. Thanks for the simple answer.

Comment: @prelic:  That's funny.  I was actually trying to answer it on an iPod touch but it's just too slow.  I managed to get the laptop open and find the question with (apparently) 7 seconds to spare.

Comment: If it were to be an output problem, how would the output look vs an sorting problem? I guess the answer vary a lot, but generally?