# Sorting integers with an array.

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I was attempting the following exercise, but got stuck in the process.

> Write a full program  that reads in an arbitrary sequence of integers 
>   from the standard input, and writes them to the standard output  in
>   sorted order and with all duplicates removed. You may assume  the
>   input contains at most 100 integers .

I have a hard time understanding arrays and attempted to figure out what it is that I need to do. I have some code written down, but I have a strong feeling I'm nowhere near completing it. I'm not asking for someone to complete it for me, I just want some guidance on how to get going, or a push in the right direction.   Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //I believe this is a start.
    int numbers [100];

    //declaring a counter
    int i;

    //making a for loop to count the integers from 1 to 100
    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
    {cin>>numbers[i];}

    //This is the point where I got lost

    if (i<100)
        cout<<numbers[i]<<""<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Since you just need guidance, probably you can start from reading this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: Do note that your code assumes that you will *always* be entering 100 integers. You might want to develop this code with only 10 integers until you think it is working well, save yourself some typing.

Comment: Also, the last line will never execute because `i` will always be 100 after the `for` loop.

Comment: In case that the wiki page is confusing this might be able to help https://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=sorting. Alternatively just search on google for *sorting algorithm tutorial*...

Comment: start from scratch brother, read about loops, conditional statements and arrays, then read about simple sort algorithm like bubble sort or insertion sort

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort some int number, you have several way that you can try some of which you want.

One way is when you read data in first loop, put data in right position in array in this way that use another loop and shift new data until arrive to smaller number. Then put new data in front of that.
 If you find equal number you can ignore new data and use **break** and get new data.

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    int temp ; 
    cin>> temp;
    int j;
    for(j = i; j>= 0 ; j--)
    {
        if(j != 0 && number[j-1]== temp)
            break ; 
        if(j != 0 && number[j-1] > temp)
        {
            number[j] = number[j-1] ;  
        }
        else
        {
            number[j] = temp ; 
            break;
        }
    }  
}
```

I think this way is best, but you have other way like:
sort all number using an algorithm like  [bubble sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612198/bubble-sort-display)  or  [Quick sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614036/stackoverflowerror-while-implementing-quicksort)  then with a loop delete all duplicate numbers.

```
int temp[100] ; 
int k = 0 ; 
temp[0] = number[0] ;
for(int i = 1 ; i < 100 ; i++)
{
    if(temp[k] != number[i])
    {
        k++; 
        temp[k] = number[i] ; 
    }
```

}